# neo4j - How to use push null values in 'order by' DESC to the bottom?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a bunch of items with property "updated" which tells when the item was updated. But bunch of timestamps are null. So when I do:
 `MATCH (item) return item ORDER BY item.updated DESC`, all those w/ null values are returned at the top.

I also tried `COALESCE`, **which seems to work in v2.2** but not in v2.1.6:

`MATCH (item) return item ORDER BY COALESCE(product.updated?,"0")  DESC`

In v2.1.6, I get:

This syntax is no longer supported (missing properties are now returned as null). Please use (not(has(.updated)) OR .updated=) if you really need the old behavior.

Is there any alternative solution that will work irrespective of the neo4j version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the CASE statement?

```
MATCH (item:Item)
RETURN CASE WHEN HAS(item.updated) THEN item.updated ELSE 0 END AS updated
ORDER BY updated DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found on Neo4j 3.1.3 that I can achieve this using a combination of `ASC` sorting and a cheeky `-` character:

```
MATCH (item:Item)
RETURN item
ORDER BY -item.updated ASC
```

This was inspired by this info about `null` and sorting in the Neo4j docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/order-by/#order-null